# Eclipse is not opening on WIN10 64bit

Tags: java, eclipse

I have Win 10 64 bit.
This is the log file in metadata folder:

```
Cannot load 64-bit SWT libraries on 32-bit JVM
```

Comment: which version of java is installed on your win 10? (use java -version on the commandline)

Comment: You seem to have a 32-bit JDK. Install a 64-bit JDK and make sure Eclipse uses the 64-bit version.

Comment: Alternatively, install the 32-bit version of eclipse (to match the 32-bit JDK).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I've installed 32-bit version and it worked!